# Kockoutjs Validation triggers errors messages on blind

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I updated ko.validation to 2.0.2 on my project for performance reasons and now all errors are showed on applyBindings.

Examples

**Before:** http://jsfiddle.net/rubenslopes/KHFn8/5392/

**After:** http://jsfiddle.net/rubenslopes/e67ho5m5/

```
 ko.validation.init({
     parseInputAttributes: true,
     insertMessages: true,
     grouping: {
         deep: true,
         observable: false
     }
 });


 var viewModel = function () {
     var self = this;

     self.name = ko.observable();
     self.saveLabel = ko.observable('Save');

     self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);
     self.isValid = ko.computed(function () {
         return self.errors().length === 0;
     }, self);
     self.showAllMessages = ko.computed(function () {
         return self.errors.showAllMessages();
     }, self);

     self.save = function () {
         if (self.isValid()) self.saveLabel('Saved!');
         else self.showAllMessages();
     };
 };
 ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Any ideas for what is happenning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your two examples are not quite the same.... if you would use the old validation plugin in your new code: http://jsfiddle.net/ex9zLfde/ it would also display the validation message initially.

So the problem is not with the plugin version but with your actual code in your `showAllMessages` computed:

```
self.showAllMessages = ko.computed(function () {
     return self.errors.showAllMessages();
 }, self);
```

Because `ko.computed`s are first evaluated when they are declared and the `self.errors.showAllMessages()` call shows the error messages you will see all the errors by the time when you apply the bindings.

To fix this you need to set the `deferEvaluation` on your computed to delay the initial evaluation:

```
 self.showAllMessages = ko.computed(function () {
     return self.errors.showAllMessages();
 }, self, {deferEvaluation : true});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/da8jn17m/).

Or you can just call `self.errors.showAllMessages()` directly in your `save` without the using a computed:

```
 self.save = function () {
     if (self.isValid()) self.saveLabel('Saved!');
     else self.errors.showAllMessages();
 };
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2g8jt8d/).